# Using NIntegrate with constants

Tags: numerical-integration

Is there any way to use the `NIntegrate` function with constants?

```
f = Exp[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]/λ]*Cos[π*x/a]*Cos[π*y/b]*Cos[π*z/c]
d = Laplacian[f, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"] // Simplify
ren = -2/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]
s = d + ren
```

The above  ' s ' is the function I would like to integrate.

Comment: If you don't specify a value for `λ`, `NIntegrate[]` won't work.

Comment: You also need bounds for the integral.  Maybe you want a function of the constants that does the integral?  Then try something like `sFcn[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_, c_, λ_] = s;` and `J[a_, b_, c_, λ_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  sFcn[x, y, z, a, b, c, λ], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]`

Comment: How could ıI do this?

Comment: @umos Use the 'at' symbol to identify who you are speaking to.  Try executing the code I posted above, and see if it does what you want.  If you have further questions, try to be more specific.

Comment: The codes you have given gives me the error as I try to evaluate function J NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand -(2/Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2])+(E^(-(Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]/\[Lambda]_)) (2 \[Pi] x Cos[(\[Pi] y)/Pattern[<<2>>]] Cos[(\[Pi] z)/Pattern[<<2>>]] a_ b_^2 c_^2 \[Lambda]_ Sin[(\[Pi] x)/Pattern[<<2>>]]+Cos[(\[Pi] x)/Pattern[<<2>>]] (<<1>>)))/(Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2] a_^2 b_^2 c_^2 \[Lambda]_^2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1},{0,1},{0,1}}.

Comment: Please go [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have your accounts merged, so that you can access your question again.

Answer (score 1):

As @J.M. said, `NIntegrate` doesn't work when the integrand is non-numerical.  You also must specify numerical bounds.  You can build a function that returns a result for arbitrarily specified numerical constants as follows

Your code:

```
f = Exp[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]/λ]*Cos[π*x/a]*Cos[π*y/b]*Cos[π*z/c];
d = Laplacian[f, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"] // Simplify;
ren = -2/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
s = d + ren;
```

My code:

```
sFcn[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_, c_, λ_] = s;
J[a_, b_, c_, λ_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   sFcn[x, y, z, a, b, c, λ], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 
    1}];
```

Example execution:

```
J[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

> `-2.36029`

The reason it works is that the constants are all numerical when `NIntegrate` is finally called.  If you insist on non-numerical input, e.g. `J[a, 1, 1, 1]`, you will get the error again (NIntegrate::inumr).