# How to tell NIntegrate to use linearity for constants?

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm performing a definite integral on a sum of 66 fairly complicated
terms. Sample term + integral (`a[2]` is a constant):

```
temp1733[n_, lat_] = 
-27501.974166279517*a[2]*
 ArcCos[-0.014543897651582656*Sec[lat]*
   Sec[0.005782961777094692 - 0.4001419318234436*Cos[0.017167172970436028*n] - 
      0.0060922154967620835*Cos[0.034334345940872056*n] - 
      0.002387468786938206*Cos[0.05150151891130809*n] + 
      0.0711242550022214*Sin[0.017167172970436028*n] + 
      0.0005863132618294766*Sin[0.034334345940872056*n] + 
      0.0013462049383894524*Sin[0.05150151891130809*n]] - 
   1.*Tan[lat]*Tan[0.005782961777094692 - 0.4001419318234436*
       Cos[0.017167172970436028*n] - 0.0060922154967620835*
       Cos[0.034334345940872056*n] - 0.002387468786938206*
       Cos[0.05150151891130809*n] + 0.0711242550022214*
       Sin[0.017167172970436028*n] + 0.0005863132618294766*
       Sin[0.034334345940872056*n] + 0.0013462049383894524*
       Sin[0.05150151891130809*n]]]*Cos[(2*n*Pi)/183]

temp1734 = Integrate[temp1733[n,lat], {n, 0.5, 366.5}, {lat,
 -60*Degree, 60*Degree}]
```

On my machine, the definite integral above times out. Since almost all my values are numerical, I'd like to use `NIntegrate`, but can't, because `a[2]` isn't a numerical value. Of course, in this case, I can simply do:

```
a[2]*NIntegrate[temp1733[n,lat]/a[2], {n, 0.5, 366.5}, {lat, 
 -60*Degree, 60*Degree}]
```

to get the answer (it happens to be `-18229.40312917879*a[2]` in this case).

However, I don't want to have to look at each of my terms to factor out the constants.

Is there any way I can tell `NIntegrate` to use linearity of integration for constants? I understand why `NIntegrate` can't handle more deeply nested constants (see [Using NIntegrate with constants](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159243/)), but it seems constants used in a purely linear way should work.

I did try things like `Coefficient` and `CoefficientList`, but they won't work in my case because the function I'm using isn't a polynomial in my constants. Even if I can't coerce `NIntegrate` to handle my functions, there must be a way to separate out and then rejoin the constant parts?

This question is a followup of sorts to the answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165937/1722 which shows a more complicated (in my opinion) way to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect):

```
Collect[
    temp1733[n,lat],
    a[2],
    NIntegrate[#,{n,0.5,366.5},{lat,-60*Degree,60*Degree}]&
]
```

> -18229.4 a[2]

Comment: That's not bad, but some of my constants are in the form `a[i]*a[j]` or `a[i]^2`. My fault for not being more specific.

Comment: @barrycarter If all your constants are of the form `a[i]`, then just use `Collect[expr, _a, NIntegrate[...]&]` instead.

Comment: That didn't do quite what I expected: I had a[1]..a[9], and the `Collect` returned 19 terms (I expected at least 9 choose 2 = 36, one for each a[i],a[j] pair), but it did work, thanks!